# I can't find an error in my code with scanf function: Return value ignored: 'scanf'

Tags: c++, scanf

Here is my code. It's in Ukrainian language, but basically, the task is:

> Determine the youngest and oldest employees through structures

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    struct worker
    {
        char surname[22], posada[15], osvita[25];
        int birthday, salary;
    };
    int kol; cout << "Введите кол-во робітників: "; cin >> kol;
    cout << "Введите поочередно строки с ведомостью:\nПрiзвище   Посада    Освіта    Рік народження   Зарплатня" << endl;

    worker* z = new worker[kol];
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        scanf("%s %s %s %i %i", z[i].surname, z[i].posada, z[i].osvita, &z[i].birthday, &z[i].salary);
    }
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Прiзвище   Посада    Освіта    Рік народження   Зарплатня" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        cout << z[i].surname << "\t" << z[i].posada << "\t" << z[i].osvita << "\t" << z[i].birthday << "\t" << z[i].salary << endl;
    }
    cout << "Найстарший і наймолодний робітники:\nПрiзвище   Посада    Освіта    Рік народження   Зарплатня" << endl;

    int min, max;
    int max_index = 0, min_index = 0;
    min = z[0].birthday;
    max = z[0].birthday;
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        if (max < z[i].birthday) {max_index = i;}
        if (min > z[i].birthday) {min_index = i;}
        printf("% s % s % s % i % i\n", z[i].surname, z[i].posada, z[i].osvita, z[i].birthday, z[i].salary);
    }
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Наймолодний робітник: " << z[min_index].surname<< endl;
    cout << "Найстарший робітник: " << z[max_index].surname << endl;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".OCP");
    delete[]z;
    return 0;
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: You should ALWAYS read the RETURN VALUE FROM SCANF(): `int retval = scanf(scanf("%s %s %s %i %i", z[i].surname, z[i].posada, z[i].osvita, &z[i].birthday, &z[i].salary);`  In this example, if "retval != 5" ... then you have a "read error", and need to handle the error accordingly.

Comment: Which C++ textbook told you about using both `cin` and `scanf` in the same program??? `scanf` is a type-unsafe C library function, and it has no business being used in a C++ program.

Comment: Programmers tend to be an interesting combination of lazy and speed obsessed. If they didn't think that return value was important, they wouldn't waste their time or the CPU's returning the value. If there's a return value, always look at it.

Comment: Refraining from writing unnecessary code just for the sake of writing it isn't "lazy" - it's a virtue.,  I'm sure there are good examples where checking the return value usually *ISN'T* important (stdio "close" comes to mind).  But with "scanf()" (and, for that matter, with "open()") ... checking the return value is ESSENTIAL.  PS: Brian Kernighan once suggested that, in programming, "laziness" *IS* a virtue.  But we digress ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 [one of my personal favourite quotes about the usefulness of laziness.](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780191826719.001.0001/q-oro-ed4-00012327;jsessionid=5C86FD5DB69269C204EA8BC968F48435) Pity the man it's attributed to never managed to kill his last boss.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` returns the number of values it successfully scanned and wrote into caller-provided variables. In this code, you are asking it to scan in 5 values, but you are not validating whether 5 values were actually output successfully before using those variables. That is what the compiler is warning you about.

For example:

```
int numScanned = scanf("%s %s %s %i %i", z[i].surname, z[i].posada, z[i].osvita, &z[i].birthday, &z[i].salary);
if (numScanned != 5) {
    // error, do something...
}   
else {
    // use variables as needed...
}
```